# Testing a 240V appliance here in the USA

Tags: transformer

I need to test a 240V appliance here in the US, how could I set up a testing environment that delivers 240V power to the appliance? Should I use a transformer or a power supply?

Comment: Is this a motorized appliance, or just heating elements and/or electronics?  Also, do you have access to a North American 240V circuit of any type?

Comment: Does the appliance require 50 or 60 cycle power ? Single or 3 phase power ? Is it to be used in the USA, Canada, Europe or elsewhere ? How much power will it require ?

Comment: 240VAC sockets are common for electric stoves, air conditioners, or electric clothes dryers.   You might plug a suitable circuit breaker into one of those sockets to make a safe power tap to plug your appliance into.

Comment: What is your **budget**?  How much **current or power** do you require for your test?  Do you require 50Hz **frequency**?  Or is your test agnostic to frequency?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a real budget ($thousands) for a professional test setup, you can just contact a supplier such as [Keysight](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaEtIXpj_jU) and buy a [power source](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5991-4194EN.pdf) designed for the purpose. It will produce various supplies used in virtually all countries worldwide. There are various sizes, expect to pay a **lot** more for higher power. A minimal 500VA unit is a few thousand dollars.

---

If your device will operate from 60Hz you can find 240VAC single phase in most non-apartment residences. In other situations you may find 208VAC or 240VAC. If 208VAC you may or may not find 3-phase power (it will be present somewhere in a structure such as an apartment building but may not be accessible in a given unit). You can convert 208 to 240 with a smallish autotransformer. The sockets will not match so you would need something like an adapter cord with a plug made to code and a non-standard European socket wired to it. The device will see 60Hz 240VAC, not the 50Hz used in Europe and many other places.

---

For relatively low power (up to 1500VA) you can buy a plug in converter transformer that will have 240VAC single phase out for 120VAC in. They're available pretty cheaply depending on the pedigree and VA, and will generally have sockets that a [Schuko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schuko) or [Europlug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europlug) will fit. Of course a transformer only converts voltage, not frequency so your device must be okay with 60Hz.

---

**NOTE**: Running some types of motors from the wrong frequency will affect the RPM and may cause them to overheat. Transformers may work okay from 60Hz and overheat at 50Hz. Many of both are rated for 50/60Hz operation, but the rotation speed of motors will change by 20% and transformers will be a bit cooler at 60Hz. Heaters generally don't care about frequency. Switching power supplies should be okay at either unless they are very marginal

Comment: Two comments about using 208 V from a 3 phase distribution to power 230 VAC equipment.  First, 208 volts is (barely) within the standard tolerance of 230 V +/- 10%, so technically any equipment designed for 230 should operate on 208 (your line may be lower, however).  Second, 208 and 240 V in the US have two hots, while in europe they use hot and neutral.  This rarely makes a difference but may make some things (such as edison lamp sockets) less safe as the more accessible "neutral" conductor is actually live.

Comment: @Evan You can convert from 208 to 240 with a smallish autotransformer. Good point on the neutral vs. two hots.